# WSGI weirdness with PYthon/Django: serving alternating old and new versions of app

Tags: python, django, apache, deployment, wsgi

I never dug into how server tech like WSGI really worked underneath and thought I had a basic understanding until now...

**What's the explanation for this type of behavior?**: On an Apache2/WSGI/Django setup, after getting the new code on the dev server and "reloading" it by doing the prescribed `touch myapp.wsgi`, things started getting weird. On successive browser refreshes, I get either the old version of the app (from before pushing the new code) or the new one, RANDOMLY! It's like some threads/processes are still serving the old code while some have loaded the new code from the disk... **What would be a simple explanation for this and how can I properly "reload" my app without restarting apache?** Or where can I find a simple (better still, graphical/schematical) explanations of how things like WSGI, FCGI etc. work.

Note: *I'm not a devops guy, but I've been forced into wrangling with things like this and I'm looking for any "condensed", "crash course type" knowledge on this, not the full fledged documentations for all the components...*

Comment: The question probably belongs here http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @rantanplan guess you're right... is there any "move" functionality on SO or should I copy paste it over there?

Comment: As I've never asked a question I don't know if you have that option. But surely a person with enough reputation will take action when he sees these comments. I just flagged it as off-topic for SO and that it belongs to serverfault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely aren't using daemon mode. Read:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html
- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

The Django documentation on mod_wsgi setup wasn't clear enough about what you had to do to use daemon mode. That has been fixed now.

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: THANKS A LOT! They really should put "If using embedded mode and you need to update the code for your Python web application, you have no choice but to restart the whole of Apache. If using daemon mode, you can avoid restarting the whole of Apache and can instead simply touch the WSGI script file to update its modification date." in a bright orange box on the Django deployment page... I just realized that on 2 projects where the reload instructions given by the sysadmin were "just touch app.wsgi", mod_wsgi was using embedded mode...

Comment: ...which lead to some weird bugs when a newer version if the client side app was talking to an older version of the api (probably running in different apache processes) ...now I just need to load my shotgun and and go find those 2 guys doing the sysadmining...